# Parallel.Foreach loop gets different result than For loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel.foreach

I've 
written simple for loop iterating through array and Parallel.ForEach loop doing the same thing. However, resuls I've get are different so I want to ask what the heck is going on? :D

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      long creating = 0;
      long reading = 0;
      long readingParallel = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
        Stopwatch timer1 = new Stopwatch();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[100000000];

        timer1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
          array[i] = rnd.Next(5);
        }
        timer1.Stop();

        long result = 0;
        Stopwatch timer2 = new Stopwatch();

        timer2.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
          result += array[i];
        }
        timer2.Stop();

        Stopwatch timer3 = new Stopwatch();
        long result2 = 0;
        timer3.Start();
        Parallel.ForEach(array, (item) =>
          {
            result2 += item;
          });

        if (result != result2)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(result + " - " + result2);
        }

        timer3.Stop();

        creating += timer1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        reading += timer2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        readingParallel += timer3.ElapsedMilliseconds;
      }



      Console.WriteLine("Create : \t" + creating / 100);
      Console.WriteLine("Read: \t\t" + reading / 100);
      Console.WriteLine("ReadP: \t\t" + readingParallel / 100);

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

So in the condition I get results:
result = 200009295;
result2 = 35163054;

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+=` operator is non-atomic and actually performs multiple operations:

- load value at location that `result` is pointing to, into memory
- add `array[i]` to the in-memory value (I'm simplifying here)
- write the result back to `result`

Since a lot of these add operations will be running in parallel it is not just possible, but likely that there will be races between some of these operations where one thread reads a `result` value and performs the addition, but before it has the chance to write it back, another thread grabs the old `result` value (which hasn't yet been updated) and also performs the addition. Then both threads write their respective values to `result`. Regardless of which one wins the race, you end up with a smaller number than expected.

This is why the [`Interlocked` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) exists.

Your code could very easily be fixed:

```
Parallel.ForEach(array, (item) =>
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref result2, item);
});
```

Don't be surprised if `Parallel.ForEach` ends up slower than the fully synchronous version in this case though. This is due to the fact that

- the amount of work inside the delegate you pass to `Parallel.ForEach` is *very* small
- `Interlocked` methods incur a slight but non-negligible overhead, which will be quite noticeable in this particular case

Comment: Thank you for wide explanation. Of course you're absolutely right!